# How to add products package in cart at once only using ajax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to do add products package in cart at once. for example i have 3 products `A, B and C`. Now i would like to add these products at once in cart as a products package.

So once it added to cart it only showing a package name not want to show products `A, B, C` and once user click on that package name particular product will be show`(A,B,C)`.

I have seen some plugins like **product bundle** but i don't want to use any plugin i would like to make this dynamically without using any plugin.

I have used following script but it's only add one product at a time not add as package in cart.

**Jquery Script**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart', function (e) {
    var product_id =$(this).attr('data-product_id');
    var product_qty =$(this).attr('data-quantity');
     e.preventDefault();

        var $thisbutton = $(this),
            $form = $thisbutton.closest('form.cart'),
            id = $thisbutton.val(),
            product_qty = product_qty,
            product_id = product_id,
            variation_id = $form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val() || 0;

        var data = {
            action: 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_sku: '',
            quantity: product_qty,
            variation_id: variation_id,
        };

       $(document.body).trigger('adding_to_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',           
            url:custom_plugin_script.ajaxurl,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (response) {
                $('#loading_img').show();
                $thisbutton.removeClass('added').addClass('loading');
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                $thisbutton.addClass('added').removeClass('loading');
            },
            success: function (response) {                
                if( response.error != 'undefined' && response.error ){                  
                    return true;
                  } else {
                     setTimeout(function() {
                        jQuery('#successMessage').show('1000');
                    }, 3000); // <-- time in milliseconds
                  }
            },
        });

        return false;
    })(jQuery);
```

Following is `PHP` script that i have put in my custom plugin main file.

```
public function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart()
    {  
          ob_start();

       $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));

       $quantity = empty($_POST['quantity']) ? 1 : wc_stock_amount($_POST['quantity']);
       $variation_id = absint($_POST['variation_id']);
       $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
       $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

      if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity, $variation_id) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

          do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);
          wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id );                
         // WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
      } else {

          $data = array(
              'error' => true,
              'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

          echo wp_send_json($data);
      } 
    die();

    }
```

Is someone have any idea about this how can id do this by problematically ?

Answer (score 0):

With the following snippet you are able to find product bundles. The function returns all bundles containing the products in cart. You have to adjust it to fit into your app by converting the data structure and add your own bundles.

Optional: products can be included in multiple bundles so take the bundle containing the most products.

```js
// your bundles
const bundles = [{
    name: "Standard",
    products: [1, 2],
  },
  {
    name: "Premium",
    products: [1, 2, 3],
  },
];

// shopping cart array with product id's
const cart = [1, 2, 3];

// returns empty array if cart does not match any bundle.
const getBundleNames = (cart) => {
  return bundles.filter((bundle) => {
    // will be false if bundle includes a product that is not included in cart
    let containsAllProducts = true;
    // itarete over riducts in bundle
    bundle.products.forEach((product) => {
      // check if cart includes product
      if (!cart.includes(product)) {
        containsAllProducts = false;
      }
    });
    return containsAllProducts;
  });
};

// optional: sort result by products length
console.log(getBundleNames(cart));
```

Best regards